# JavaScript validation for date return always false

Tags: javascript

i am trying to validate date which Accept only dd/mm/yyyy.

i have use the following code to validate but it always show me alert.

what wrong with my code ??

when i used ,
**var bevalue ='10/10/1989';**  it work fine.

And in my code i used,
**value = $(this).val();**   to get value.

then convert it to string

EDIT:

```
$('input, textarea').live('blur', function () {
        var field = $(this).attr('name');
        var value = $(this).val();

if(field=='birthday')
  {   
        var bevalue = String(value);   
        var regbday =/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d+$/;
        if(regbday.test(bevalue) == false)
        {
            alert('please Enter Birth date in dd/mm/yyyy');
           return false;
        }
}
```

Thanks Everyone for reply my mistake in Regexp. I accepted answer.

Comment: What's `this` ? We need more code. And you should first debug to see what's `value`.

Comment: What dystroy is saying is that the code you've posted isn't the cause of the problem.  As a side note, you should use `?:` to prevent sub-expressions from being captured if you're not using them.

Comment: I tested it where value is fake and it works fine. Minus the fact that at the end you are capturing an unlimited amount of numbers `+`. So therefore I can enter in `10/10/12345679`. Removing the `+` fixes that. if it isn't working, then `value` is wrong and to help we will need to understand how you are getting value's value like @dystroy said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the regular expression that's not correct,

```
function checkBday(bevalue) {
    var regbday = /(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\.\/\-](0[1-9]|1[012])[\.\/\-](19|20)\d\d/;
    if (regbday.test(bevalue) == false) {
        alert(bevalue + ' is not valid\nplease Enter Birth date in dd/mm/yyyy');
        return false;
    }
    return true
}
console.log(checkBday("14.03.2013")) //true
console.log(checkBday("14-03-2013")) //true
console.log(checkBday("14/03/2013")) //true
console.log(checkBday("14.03.12")) //false
console.log(checkBday("12.28.2013")) //false
console.log(checkBday(prompt("Enter Birthday in dd/mm/yyyy")));
```

This should work, heres an example on [JSBIn](http://jsbin.com/oxitab/1/edit)

*Edit*
If you only want to match dates which use `/` as delimiter change the regexp to
`/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(19|20)\d\d/`

Comment: I thought he is refereing to the format with `dd/mm/yyyy` and not to delimiter of the format, as he is matching against `.` `/` `-` in his regexp too

Comment: I guess so. The question is worded odd. My bad.

Comment: Nevermind =), i updated the answer anyway in case the op really only wants to match `/`

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong reg-exp, the day and month parts are switched and some characters are not escaped.

Use this formula:

```
var regbday = /^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\- \/\.](0[1-9]|1[012])[\- \/\.](19|20)\d\d+$/;
```